# manage multiple messages from content-script to a vue js popup page in google-chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Vue and trying to do my first chrome extension.
I am trying to update the popup page every time an event happens in the content(mouse up in my case)
I am completely lost on how to handle the situation. here is my code.

**content-script**

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
 
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "textMessage": { data: "some string"} });
 
 }
```

**app.vue // component file**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
 
    <h3>message: {{message} </h3>
    <hr />
   
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  
  data() {
    return {
      message: "0"
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function ({ textMessage }, sender, response) {
       this.message = textMessage.data; //should I emit a custom event here??

    })

  }
}



</script>
```

In the example I just mounted the chrome api to receive the message. What I want to do is emit a custom event whenever a new message  is emitted and update the data object. The problem is that it looks like I cannot access $data.message from the chrome api, I can console.log it if I do something like this:

```
mounted(){
  var text = this.message;

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function ({ textMessage }, sender, response) {
           console.log(text
    
        })
}
```

but I can't update the $data object even if I do the same under `computed` or `methods`.

Could you anyone point out the best wat to update the $data object everytime we receive a message from content please?

Comment: Declare the listener inside `methods` object of your component so it becomes bound to `this`, then use `this.listenerName` in addListener.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I'll try and update you

Comment: @wOxxOm I kind of solved like this.. but I don't feel it right.. 

` 
data() {
    return {
      message: []
    }
  },
  methods: {

    updateMessage: function () {
      let m = this.message;

      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function ({ textMessage }, sender, response) {
        console.log(m[0])// does consoles the correct value
        m.push(textMessage.title);// does add the text in the array
      })

    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.updateMessage()
  }
}
`